# Why can't I see the file version of files in system32 remotely?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-permissions

Here's the situation:

I can RDP into a computer, go to C:\Windows\System32, and check file versions to my heart's content. Such as winlogon.exe, explorer.exe, etc.

If I map the drive, and try to check the file version, I can't see it. It's blank. Winlogon, explorer, services, all of these executable files have no file version when I'm checking them over the network.

A scanning program I use, which uses the same credentials, can't read the file version remotely, but can locally.

So it seems something is preventing file versions in that folder from being read remotely. I checked the permissions on the System32 folder, and it looks good. I also changed the Owner of the folder to the local admin group, which my user is a part of, just to make sure. Still can't see the file version.

I haven't been able to find any information on if there's a local security policy  or GPO that prevents information in certain folders from being read remotely. Checking policies manually has yielded nothing as well, though I haven't checked every single one yet.

So I set up some virtual machines, made a new domain, tried to see these file versions over the network. And I can.

In both cases, the user is a Domain Admin, and no changes have been made to the group's permissions from the default ones. In both cases, I'm mapping the C$ share and then navigating to the windows\system32 directory. I've replicated the issue on 10 servers, and I've changed the mapping server and mapped server. Nothing new, still can't see. The servers are all Windows Server 2012 R2.

Is there a GPO or permission I'm missing or something?

Does anyone know why file version attributes are being blocked over the network?

Comment: This is a curiosity but I don't see how this is a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm a developer for a program that scans machines remotely to determine installed and missing patches. Some patches are determined by file version. Can't read file version = bad results.